# Webdev.webserver.exe stopped working

Tags: wcf, deployment

When i am trying to browse the svc file i am getting an error

Webdev.Webserver.exe stopped working properly...

Can solutions to solve the problem

Comment: Could you be a bit more vague?  Adding things like what the svc looks like, what binding is use or if there is any information in the Windows Event Log would make it entirely too easy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this if two tings on the same machine are trying to use the same port. Try changing the port number in your solution.

See: http://jberke.blogspot.com/2008/07/webdevwebserverexe-has-stopped-working.html